# Estimate Shipping and Tax removed (show transport costs)

Tags: shipping, magento-1, shipping-methods, tax, estimate

I removed "Estimate Shipping and Tax" by doing this:

```
<!-- 
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
-->
```

But how do i get the transport costs in the cart vieuw now?
i only got 1 transport cost and its 5,95 so it should just always show this.
(ps. there is a cart promotion code that makes it 0 after 500 euro)

Is there a way? maybe force the estimate shipping and tax to estimate the Netherlands in the back automatic?

Thanks in advance.

- 4-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 5-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 6-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 7-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 8-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 9-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 13-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 14-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 15-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 16-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 18-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 19-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 20-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 23-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 26-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 29-4-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 4-5-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 6-5-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 9-5-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 10-5-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 11-5-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution
- 6-6-2016 this topic is still unsloved, i'm stil hoping for an solution

Comment: ps. for example if you add this product to the cart you won't see the transportcosts. http://verwarmland.nl/biomassa/toebehoren/installatie-onderdelen/thermisch-veiligheidsventiel.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this block to static block with your information. I think that it's better. If at some point you decide to add additional delivery methods, you can replace always your static unit back to normal.

Comment: hello, thank you for the reply. i do not get how i can force the tax and transport to put in the netherlands with a static block. and about the additional delivrey methods, i only deliver in a small area so i can deliver to everywhere with just 1 price. so i don't want te customer get confused with this calculation of tax and prices and i don't want to hidde the transport cost until the last page asswel, it should just show 5,95 in the cart same as it whould when u put in where u are from.